# How to allow multiple passwords in php?

Tags: php

How do i allow access to a website with more than 1 password - in this example i would like to allow both small and capital letters in 'myname':

```
<?php
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if($pass == 'myname' and 'MYNAME') { // THIS IS NOT WORKING
        include("navigation-web-musik-grafik.php");

    echo "<script>
            document.getElementById('hide_when_pass').style.display = 'none';
        </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: for future reference, if you wanted to use "and" its &&

Comment: Why did i raise the question if i knew that 'and' was working? Sometimes hmm..

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize "and" was valid syntax

Comment: Its not working - thats the reason i made a comment

Comment: Its the point of the question - looking for the correct syntax of "and" in PHP -

Comment: It wasn't working due to logic, not syntax.  I thought you made a syntactical error as well, I was incorrect.

Comment: Maybe not - i done same mistake in previous questions - i have to restrict code to what i have, and let the question itself explain the result i would like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Err your using a little weird syntax there.

```
if($pass == 'myname' || $pass == 'MYNAME') {
```

Comment: No problemo. Your original post actually really peaked my curiousity for a few minutes because I ran it through 3v4l.org is it was actual logically true, then I realised that "MYNAME" is always returning true because in the statement its just returning true :D I thought I had a 'mind blown' moment.

Answer (score 3):

$pass can not logically equal two different values, use the OR operator

```
if($pass == 'myname' || $pass == 'MYNAME')
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

If however all you want to achieve is case insensitivity, you can convert the $pass variable to lower case and check that:

```
if(strtolower($pass) == 'myname')
```